# adding radio button handle to ajax script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

this ajax function gets a textbox value and sends it to `"response.php"`: (this is main function of `ajax.js`)

```
function ajaxFunction() {
  var getdate = new Date(); 

  if(xmlhttp) {

    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");

    xmlhttp.open("POST","response.php",true); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value); 
  }
}
```

i am trying to add a radio button set to my form, so i changed this to:

```
function ajaxFunction() {

  var getdate = new Date();  
  if(xmlhttp) {

    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    var radio = document.getElementById("radio2"); //ADDED

    xmlhttp.open("POST","response.php",true); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value); 
    xmlhttp.send("radio=" + radio.value); //ADDED

  }
}
```

and in response.php :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['txtname'])){
 $radio =  $_POST['radio'];

       //process...

}

?>
```

input text still works but radio buttons not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem that your variable name is not "radio2" but "radio".

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['txtname'])){
   // $radio =  $_POST['radio2']; // <-- here
   $radio =  $_POST['radio']; // fixed

     //process...
}
?>
```

Because you post the data by the name of "radio".

```
xmlhttp.send("radio=" + radio.value); //ADDED
```

-----ADDED MY ANSWER BELOW ----

And please try ...

```
xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value + "&radio="+ radio.value);
```

or

```
xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value + "&radio2="+ radio.value);
```

Because you can not use xmlhttp.send() twice.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i changed this when testing different ways..
in this way, values only added in `response.php?ect..` url but i cant handle values in page itself. it brokes ajax funcionality. but i edited my question anyway.

Comment: Could you show me your HTML code ? <input type="radio" name="...">

Comment: thats it
 `<input type="radio" name="choose" id="radio2" value= "c1"/><label for="radio2">choice1</label>
 <input type="radio" name="choose"  id="radio2" value= "c2" /><label for="radio2">choice2</label>`

Answer (score 1):

Bind post parameters in one and post

```
  var parameters = 'radio='+radio.value+'&txname='+txtname.value;
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);
```